# RCP Application do not export product with Babel feature

Tags: eclipse, plugins, export, eclipse-rcp

I use Eclipse 4.14 for an old RCP application that I updated to Java 8. Now it is possible to export the product but as soon as I add the feature "org.eclipse.babel.nls_eclipse_de" for the German language to the product in the "Contents" part the following error appears:

Processing inclusion from feature org.eclipse.babel.nls_eclipse_de: Bundle org.eclipse.ant.tests.core.nl_de_4.22.0.v20211218020001 failed to resolve.:
Host plug-in org.eclipse.ant.tests.core_0.0.0 has not been found.

The application do start in German. I only have problems with the export of the product.

Edit:
The run configuration noticed plug-ins are missing. Launching is possible. Export is not possible because of "missing" plug-ins. I do not understand why they are missing.

[Screenshot of missing plug-ins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SopI.png)

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution? I added org.eclipse.babel.nls_eclipse_de also under content in my product. I don't get an error message, but it is still on english. How did you configure it?

I also have added -nl de to my program arguments

<features>
      <feature id="application.feature" version="4.35.1.qualifier"/>
      <feature id="org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full" installMode="root"/>
      <feature id="org.eclipse.babel.nls_eclipse_de"/>
   </features>